# Parenting an appended object

Tags: modeling, objects

I'm a Blender Newbie and I'm having trouble selecting & parenting an appended object. As an exercise I have a scene of a simple room, the cube, to which I've appended a mesh chair. I now want to scale, position and then parent this to room. However, I can't find a way to select chair and then the room. 
What should I do?

Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Right-click the chair, and then <kbd>Shift</kbd>+right-click the room. (Although I can't really think why you would want to do this.)

Comment: I'm doing this as a simple exercise in appending & parenting. Your method works OK in object mode the 2 items scale & move as one but in edit mode they act as separate items, although they are linked in the outliner. I'm working my way through Noob to Pro and I've just noticed that there is the same problem with the assembled Jeep

Comment: I've realised that I'm trying to do something that perhaps Blender isn't designed to do & that I don't need to do. My ultimate aim is to make an animation inside the living area of a house. I've modeled most of this and in their own files a door & handle. I've been trying to append, re-scale, position & parent these two before finishing editing the main living area. I can now see that if I fix them in place I won't be able to animate them later so is the correct plan to finish all modeling first before appending & parenting all into one scene?

Comment: Are they in separate files?

Comment: And you can absolutely animate them later, although I don't know what you mean by "fixing them in place". (Also, if you're planning to keep them in separate files and work on the individual files to edit the pieces, it's probably better to link instead of append them.)

Comment: Most items will be in separate files. An example of 'fixed' would be a table on the floor of the room. No matter how I scale or move the room in the 3d window the table would keep it's place & relative size. Thanks for your help seaturtle, it's people like you that keep people like me from getting too frustrated and giving up.

Comment: So you're moving/scaling the room, and want the table to follow? Sounds like parenting is the way to go, then. Glad I could help. (:

Comment: Also, once you're done moving everything, if you want to unparent the table, be sure to select Keep Transform—otherwise the table will just jump back to its original location.